# Allow image to be wider than containing div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Is there any way to make a div not extend it's width, but make an image which is visible outside the div in IE8? For example, my div might be 200px wide, but the image 250px wide.

Comment: Have you tried using max-width? Not sure if the container should be smaller than an element within it, but if you need to, try max-width and see if it helps. Consequently, for a min width you can also use min-width.

Comment: yes i used but it remains the same....

Comment: @SagarPatil: in all other browser it works fine except IE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could position the image 'absolute'?

```
div > img {position:absolute;}
```

Comment: This will give you the desired effect. Although personally i believe the container should always be large enough to hold it's contents. Maybe a different approach is required

Comment: @marc constello:yep i tried that too, but the main thing is when i increase the width of the  image the container div also increasing according to the width of the image  so the image always be inside the container.. any way to fix this...?

Comment: Are you giving the images set widths and heights?

Comment: @marc constello:container div width:200px; image width:250px; and container div set with overflow:visible

Comment: @krish the overflow:visible is not needed. just add div > img {position:absolute;}

Comment: This should actually work. The absolute takes the image out of the regular flow of the document and hence will place it outside of the divs structural flow. Since it's out of the flow, the div should not expand. As @MarcCostello suggested, try it without the overflow.

Comment: @MarcCostello and Sagar patil: in IE the issue is fixed guys absolute was play its role... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Set the div's `width` to `200px` and its `overflow` to `visible`.

Comment: i used this but it remains the same

Comment: But it works; I tested in IE8. Can you post the code you tried?